# How to get permission forever?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-bluetooth

I am developing an app i which user set timer after timer finished Bluetooth should be automatically turned off

I am using this code

```
<manifest ... >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
...

</manifest>



class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var bAdapter:BluetoothAdapter?=null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        bAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()

        val time=findViewById<EditText>(R.id.time)
        var interval:Long=0

        val textView=findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview)
        val btn=findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn)

        btn.setOnClickListener {

            if(time.text.isNotEmpty())
            {
                if(time.text.toString()=="")
                {
                    interval=0
                }
                else
                    interval=time.text.toString().toLong()*1000
                Log.d("yash","$interval")
            }

            object : CountDownTimer(interval, 1000) {
                override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {

                    val f: NumberFormat = DecimalFormat("00")
                    val hour = millisUntilFinished / 3600000 % 24
                    val min = millisUntilFinished / 60000 % 60
                    val sec = millisUntilFinished / 1000 % 60
                    textView.setText(
                        f.format(hour).toString() + ":" + f.format(min) + ":" + f.format(
                            sec
                        )
                    )

                }

                // When the task is over it will print 00:00:00 there
                override fun onFinish() {
                    turnoff()
                }
            }.start()
        }



    }
    fun turnoff()
    {
        bAdapter!!.disable()
    }
```

Problem is app ask for permission every time after timer is over I want to ask one time when user open app and then no need to ask for permission(because user is not available to give permission) how to do that ?

Comment: Permission for what? Shouldn't you tell that in your post? And title of your post?

Comment: Permission to turn off Bluetooth, i have mentioned in post

Comment: ??? You are not mentioning that in your post or title.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this code help you. call this method requestPermission1(); and give permisstion inside

```
private void requestPermission1() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, req);

}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {
            if (permissions.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                prolay1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              Toast.makeText(getapplicationcontext(), "Permission allowed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

             else {
                Toast.makeText(getapplicationcontext(), "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //   requestPermission();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But the author has asked for different permission, not `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. So change your answer accordingly.

Comment: I want for Bluetooth permission

Comment: Write permission inside this                   
   Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH}